# Function executing itself without being called

Tags: go

I started to learn Go yesterday on the Tour of Go website and I thought that I was understanding everything well;

But then I was totally confused on the exercise Stringers: https://tour.golang.org/methods/18

So I searched a solution to see what I was doing wrong and I found this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.

func (i IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])   

 }

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

and the output is this:

```
loopback: 127.0.0.1
googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
```

it left me completely confused;

Why did the function activate itself? Should'nt it be like: i.String() inside the main func?

Why did the fmt.Printf show nothing on the screen at all?

Or the fmt.Printf returned that because the String() changed the value?

I'm sorry if the question is confusing, but can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [the previous page in the tutorial](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17), you see that `Stringer` is [an interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) defined in the `fmt` package. Implementing the `String()` method [automatically](https://tour.golang.org/methods/10) makes `IPAddr` implement this interface.

The `fmt.Printf` function checks if its argument implements the `Stringer` interface. Since it now does, it calls the `String` method when it needs to figure out how to show an `IPAddress` (you can change this behavior by using a format specifier other than `%v`, but that's beyond the scope of the question).

The `fmt.Printf` call showed something; it showed the lines

```
loopback: 127.0.0.1
googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
```

It didn't change their value or anything; it just called the `String` method to figure out how to write down an `IPAddr`, and wrote it down that way.

Comment: Thank you so much! Guess i didn't pay attention to the pages, but, can you explain to me that %v thing?

Comment: Sure. The [rules for how `Printf` converts values to strings](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) are a bit complicated, but in general if you say `%v` it'll try to make a human-readable representation, if you say `%#v` prints what you'd need to write to get that value as a variable in Go, you can use various characters other than `v`, such as `%x`, to print in various specialized formats (I'm not sure what this does for user-defined types), and `%%` will give you an actual percent sign.